# Thread Synchronization and member function

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, visual-c++, synchronization

I have four threads with 'this' pointer as the thread parameter.
In these threads I am calling same member function using the reinterpret_casted this pointer. This member function uses the member variables ( non static ) for reading only. But the application crashed and the crash dump shows the application crashed when calling the member function from threads.

```
DWORD MyClass::Thread1( LPVOID ParamPtr )
{
     MyClass* MyClassPtr = reinterpret_cast<MyClass*>( ParamPtr );
     for(i......)
     {
         for( j..... )
         {
             // a.b.c are local variables
             MyClassPtr->MyFunc( a, b, c );  <-  Crashed
             ...............
             MyClassPtr->member1 = 1;
         }
     }
  }
```

Similar code in Thread2, Thread3 & Thread4 which modifies the different member variables.

Comment: This sure looks like C++, but the liberal use of non-standard types make my suspect it's not `std::thread` you're trying to synchronize. I had a stab at the tags, please correct me if I guessed wrong.

Comment: An MCVE would make this easy to answer

Answer (score 0):

Calling a member function requires a valid `this` pointer, which `reinterpret_cast` may not give you. That cast is really a "I know what I'm doing, trust me" cast. And the crash suggests you didn't. The compiler blindly believed `MyClassPtr` pointer to a `MyClass` object, and it obviously didn't.

As to why, that's impossible to say from this code. With this type of threading (Win32 native), it's up to you to make certain the stars align. The object could have been destroyed elsewhere (C++ has no garbage collection, it won't keep objects alive for you). You may have a pointer offset issue, due to the cast.

Comment: Yes, I agree with your comment.  I forget to mention that MyClass is an independent class: it has no inheritance. So I think the pointer offset issue may not happen. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty clear that `MyClass` was allocated on stack (automatic storage), or allocated on heap, but later deleted before this function (`MyFunc`) is called.

Or, it is very much possible that what you passed to thread is not `MyClass` but something else. You should always pass correct type and ensure it remain in memory for the thread to use it.